# Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONTENT_LENGTH_MISMATCH in Angular 7 Http.get

Tags: angular, http, rxjs, observable

I am searching the solution for 
**Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONTENT_LENGTH_MISMATCH**

[image]

I am working on angular, and always facing error, whenever tried to fetch data by using http.get and no of element in the object is more than 50-60k.
if we change API(build on Nodejs) and send data in fixed size bundle multiple time than it is working, but I want to handle these issue in angular not in node.

service

```
    constructor(private url: string, private http: HttpClient) {
      }
      getAll() {
        return this.http.get(this.url)
        .map(response => response)
        .catch(this.handleError);
      }
```

Component

```
    constructor(
        private service:dataService) { }

      return this.service.getAll()
        .subscribe(data=>this.datas=data)
```

I know this question is looking like duplicate , but I haven't got solution or suggestion to takle this issue.

Comment: Don't give for granted that you can handle it with Angular. If the server is giving you a meaningless or problematic response, then the best way to act is changing the server code

Comment: @DineshGopalChand this code is working? i think same mistakes are there 'return' i component `missed function` and also `get` instead of 'getAll'

Comment: I can see those data by opening the URL directly in the browser, Yaa it is taking time to load completely , but it is loading completely. 
Since it is taking more time to load. observable.subscribe is not working that might be due to waiting time or huge data